# Why are some jars not added to .classpath file in eclipse by maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, eclipse-classpath

I would like to add the following dependency to a maven (I'm not using the m2e plugin).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>uk.com.robust-it</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloning</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem is that the jar simply is not added to the .classpath file in eclipse when I execute `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`. It works fine for this dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven does donwload cloning the dependency. The correct .jar file is in `~/.m2/repositories`. I also tried `mvn eclipse:configure-workspace` before executing `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`. Didn't help either. Running `mvn clean compile test integration-test` works fine, even if I add imports to classes in cloning.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which Eclipse do you use?

Comment: Run mvn with -X and see if there's anything being logged that could be affecting it.

Comment: Eclipse Modeling Tools
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

Comment: @Goibniu I am working on an eclipse plugin. The log shows the same for cloning and jdom2, but cloning is not added to the manifest file and jdom2 is added. You can look at the log yourself here [link](http://pastebin.com/uwybrZLJ).

Answer (score 1):

Try a

```
 mvn help:effective-pom
```

to see if the `scope` is `provided`